# Connect to SQL Server Express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

According to the below link, We can connect to SQL Server host in Node.js

[connect to msserver in Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

But in this SQL Server version, it's necessary to install software and set some the setting for it.

The easy way to SQL Server database is an express version

In this version, We can connect to the SQL server database directly and without install any software

Actually, like Sqlite that no need to install any software

Unfortunately, I cannot find node.js npm for use express version

Can you help me with how do use it?

Comment: Have you had a read of the tutorial on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/node-js-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), that shows them connecting to a Azure SQL Database (Connecting to a local instance would be the same)

Comment: @Larnu I try to read it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution for stand-alone database :)

You can use mini server MySQL

It's lightweight, high speed

Only run start_server.bat and use client MySQL to connect to it

Download from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/MiniServer/MiniServer_%20MySQL%205.0.67%20Portable/mini_server_11.exe/download